# Cities XL 2012 offices/industry deadlock

Tags: cities-xl-2012

I'm playing Cities XL 2012 since a while.

I noticed that too oftenly I end up having large areas for offices that don't develop. Clicking on those shows that "it's hard to obtain Tech industry". Alright, I say, let's develop the tech. But then I find undeveloped tech areas that require office services.

Buying from OmniCorp is usury (I'm currently -27 office coins).
Checking the population, I see I have enough executives and qualified workers for the office, so I don't see why they don't develop. Buying a few tech from OmniCorp doesn't solve. Also, I don't think I have hotel problems because otherwise I would read it.

What is the best way to develop offices in a city? I would also like to export those offices to other towns if possible (I have a very high people capacity).

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be `density`.

High-density offices require hi-tech, which require simply *offices*. Building small offices seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

are the offices intended to change out worker level as you unlock higher level people? first started the city it only took skilled workers then i unlocked exec's then it was skilled and exec's, just unlocked elites, and now it's exec's and elites. for all Density's

as for the question, low density helped me out.  not sure on the reason though.